# How can I reproduce the style shown in this tea cup photo?

Tags: lighting, technique, glass

I tried the flash and ISO and the Aperture, but it's hard to produce such effect. I am wondering that is there any tricks here? Please suggest...

My camera is Canon 500D in M mode.
The picture is:
http://fineartamerica.com/featured/green-tea-skip-hunt.html

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the exif of [this photo on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/plantainsandkimchi/5016374023/) you will see a low aperture and high iso and probably just overexposed it a bit. Flash produce a different effect than this. A weak light source(es) far off gives the feel and with longish exposure gives bloom; high iso lowers the dynamic range and possibly a wider aperture lens gives some blur.

Obviously the results are different because of different angles and lighting positions.

If you can get the flash off your camera and aim it from the side or get say an 18" 15w fluorescent light and move it around it will give different effects.

Playing with the ratio of ambient lighting and flash power vs exposure time/aperture will then be factored in too.

All in all, theres a bunch of parameters to fiddle with on the camera, lighting sources, strengths, positions and diffusion and you'd probably spend hours in front of a little cup before you get a similar shot but then in the process discover a zillion new shots in between all that.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the shadow that the spoon is casting on the saucer. It is a very sharp shadow, suggesting a small light source, such as a flash far away from the subject. Looks like the light is coming almost from above.

It looks like the saucer is sitting on a glass table. Underneath it is black, which can be achieved by putting a black cloth down.

Looks like a long(ish) lens was used, maybe 85 or 135, from the flat perspective. Shoot open f/4 or so.

Get some water, add food coloring (yellow/red) and experiment.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that there is a reflection of the light from some brass surface, or yellow gel on the light source, which contribute to the general color cast.